# PHP:unable to echo a variable from DB

Tags: php, ajax, echo, chat

I'm writing a chat script but I have problem with `echo` some variables!

I have written this piece of code in **chat.php** to show the messages:

```
<?php
session_start();
$id=$_GET['id'];
if(isset($id)){
global $id;
global $qs;
global $answerer;
global $sp;
global $name;
include('config.php');
$conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8;",$username,$password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$id=$conn->quote(htmlentities($id));
$find=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM qs WHERE id=:id");
$find->bindParam(':id',$id);
$find->execute();
if($rows=$find->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $qs=$rows['question'];
    $answerer=$rows['answerer'];
}
$answerer=explode("(",$answerer);
$ansgiver=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ruhani WHERE name=:answerer");
$ansgiver->bindParam(':answerer',$answerer[0]);
$ansgiver->execute();
if($row=$ansgiver->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $name=$row['username'];
    $avatar=$row['avatar'];
    $sp=$row['sp'];
}
class chat {
    public function fetchMessage() {
        include('config.php');
        global $id;
        $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8;",$username,$password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $ans=$conn->prepare("SELECT answere FROM ans WHERE q_id=:id ");
        $ans->bindParam(':id',$id);
        $ans->execute();
    }
    public function throwMessage($id, $text,$sayer){
        include('config.php');
        global $id;
        $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8;",$username,$password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $send=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ans(q_id,answere,sayer)  VALUES(:q_id,:text,:sayer) ");
        $send->bindParam(':q_id',$id);
        $send->bindParam(':text',$text);
        $send->bindParam(':sayer',$sayer);
        $send->execute();
    }
}
$chat = new chat();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Example Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chat.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="all">
<div class="env">
<span><?php echo $name ?>|<?php echo $sp ?></span>
<span>Hi,Can I help you?</span><br>
<span>me:<?php echo $qs ?></span>
<div class="messages"></div>
</div>
<textarea name="ask_ans" class="ask_ans" id="ask_ans" placeholder="Please write here!"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="send"  />
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" value=<? echo $id ?> />
<input type="hidden" id="hidden2" value=<? echo $_SESSION['$username'] ?> />
</div>
</body>
<?php
}
?>
```

and this code for Ajax part(**chat.js**):

```
var chat = { }
chat.fetchMessage=function (){
    $.ajax({
        url:"send.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {method : 'fetch'},
        cache:false,
        success: function(data){
            $(".all .env .messages").html(data)
        }
    });
}
chat.throwMessage=function (id,message,sayer){
    if($.trim(message).length != 0 ){
        $.ajax({
            url:"send.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {method : 'throw' , id : id , message : message , sayer : sayer  },
            cache:false,
            success: function(data){
                chat.fetchMessage();
                $(".ask_ans").val('');
            }
        });
    }
}
chat.entry=$(".all .submit");
chat.entry.bind('click',function (evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    chat.throwMessage($("#hidden").val(),$(".ask_ans").val(),$("#hidden2").val());
});
chat.interval=setInterval(chat.fetchMessage(),5000);
chat.fetchMessage()
```

And this is **send.php**:

```
<?php
require('chat.php');
if (isset($_POST['method']) and !empty($_POST['method'])){
    $chat   =new chat();
    $method =trim($_POST['method']);
    if ($method === 'fetch'){
        $messages=$chat->fetchMessage();
        if (!empty($messages)){
            while($r=$messages->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $sayer=$r['sayer'];
                if($sayer===$starter){
                    ?>
                    <span class="text" style="float:left"><? echo $r['answere'] ?></span>
                    <?php
                }else{
                    ?>
                    <span class="text" style="float:right"><? echo $r['answere'] ?></span>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        }
    }else if ($method === 'throw'){
        $message=trim(htmlentities($_POST['message']));
        $id=trim(htmlentities($_POST['id']));
        $sayer=trim(htmlentities($_POST['sayer']));
        if(!empty($message) and !empty($id) and !empty($sayer)){
            $chat->throwMessage($id,$message,$sayer);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I am getting an error:

> Undefined index:id

My problem is that I can't echo `$qs`,`$name`,`$sp` in chat.php.

Can anyone understand the wrong part of my code?

Comment: Have you checked your error logs or your browser's console?

Comment: **PLEASE** don't just dump all your code, do some debugging and find out what code could be related to the error and then post that code instead of just dumping it all.

Comment: Yes,in error_log I saw just Undefined index:id.I tried solve it by using isset() but failed

Comment: @Expodax as I said I don't know what the problem is.So I post those codes.I'm sorry:(

Comment: Learn how to debug, debugging your code is as much part of writing code as actually writing it is.

Comment: well `<input type="hidden" id="hidden" value=<? echo $id ?> />` is missing a name attribute so that should most likely read as `<input type="hidden" id="hidden" value=<? echo $id ?> name="id" />` *give that a whirl.* make sure short tags are ON too. same goes for `<input type="hidden" id="hidden2" value=<? echo $_SESSION['$username'] ?> />` no name attribute. and/or `hidden="id"`

Comment: *Eagle-eye Ralph!* @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Blowing on fingers Sam* - @JayBlanchard ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- you are right but I'm not sure that this is related yo my problem!

Comment: try adding form tags.

Comment: Fred's comment is *exactly* related to your problem if you have an undefined id error @Mr.NaViD

Comment: Yes,but that's not all.As I said I have problem to echo some variables. @Jay Blanchard

Comment: and as I mentioned earlier, if short tags are not enabled, then you need to change all `<?` to `<?php` and if you have `<?=` to "echo", then you need to use full method `<?php echo`, *just saying*. This may be a contributing factor to many. We also don't know if you constructed your class correctly neither. Like `$this->method->...` etc.

Comment: Once you have `id` defined your variables should echo. You have a truckload of possible problems and each must be eliminated to be successful.

Comment: last ditch effort `$id=trim(htmlentities($_POST['id']));` try a GET instead.

Comment: My short tags are enable.And I defined the `id` ,`<input type="hidden" id="hidden" value=<? echo $id ?> name="id" />` as Fred-ii- said.

Comment: I'm sending the id to `send.php` with post So I can't use GET. @Fred-ii-

Comment: then `$id=$_GET['id'];` => `$id=$_POST['id'];` - I won't be able to help you anymore from there, sorry. I don't know all the answers to this one, good luck.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm getting the id from user through Get and I am sending this id to send.php via POST.take a look at chat.js please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long time I checked my code,I understand the problem:)

As you see I'm using PDO::quote() and it puts `' '` over the word.So that When I was exploding the variable here:`$answerer=explode("(",$answerer);`,it couldn't find the correct word to search in DB and didn't `echo` the variable.

And now I have deleted PDO::quote() and my code is working correct.:-)